# swift xcode - navigationitem.rightbarbuttonitem not showing image literal though just appearing blue

Tags: swift, xcode

[just showing blue and not image literal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmDx9.png)

My rightBarButtonItem is just showing blue and not the image literal?

```
    NavigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Contacts Book"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleNewMessage))
```

Comment: Have you checked that this piece of code is executed by break point? Can you change the image literal to the old fashioned UIImage(named:"ImageName") and give it a try?

Comment: @Fangming Ning  - going to the old fashioned way gives the same result

Answer (score 0):

I think it's safe to assume this isn't a png with a transparent background.

barButtonItems take pngs and fill every existing pixel with default color blue.

You can change the color, but I assume you don't want any other block in place of the blue one.

You can either find a way to make this not a bar button item or you can edit your image to take the background out.

**Something like this:**

[image]

**Works better than something like this:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set property of your image that is below:

```
Step1:Go to Assets.xcssets
Step2:Select your imageset
Step3:Go to property inspector
Step4:In imageset you need to set Original Image into Render as property.
```

[image]

Comment: where is property inspector? @brijesh Shiroya

Answer (score 0):

```
  it worked by doing this 

    NavigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named:"Grape")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleNewMessage))
```

now it shows the actual image and not just a complete blue image